# rescaling time difference between video frames

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn

I have a video of transport happening. Each frame looks like this:

[image]

I have calculated something time-derivative like. if f(i) is the i-th frame, the following image is 2*f(i)-f(i+1)-f(i-1):

[image]

The moving particles have a more distinct signature in this time derivative video. The problem is I cannot actually make it a video, since linear combinations of float images (with intensities on [-1,1]) are not necessarily float images (because intensities are not on the range [-1,1]). Therefore I would like to rescale the images to be on [-1,1].

I tried to use sklearn's preprocessing module:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

images = [image1, image2, ...] 
#each imagek is a 1D image array 

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler([-1,1])
scaler.fit(images)

rescaled_images = scaler.transform(images)
```

This method amplifies noise and removes the contrast.
[image]

Any recommendation as to how I can rescale these time derivative images to [-1,1] without losing information? Any help is appreciated !

(I asked yesterday, but deleted the question because I didn't have the time to properly indicate the problem with graphics)

Comment: The reason for this is because `MinMaxScaler` is applying a transformation on each column of your data. You want an imagewise scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment the reason that it's not working is because `MinMaxScaler` is for feature scaling, but you want to scale you entire image. Assuming your image are `numpy` arrays, your easiest way would be as follows:

```
# create a 128x128 image to work with
image = np.random.random((128, 128),)
# scale to [0, 1]
newimage = (image - image.min()) / (image.max() - image.min())
# Now scale to [-1, 1]
newimage = newimage*2-1
print(newimage.min(), newimage.max())
```

**Output:** -1.0, 1.0

Comment: Works great -- thank you! This solution is pretty simple. I had decided the lesson to learn from the failure of MinMaxScaler was that such a linear scaling wouldn't be good enough, since the contrast was low.